# Problem using align* using [ ] and ( )

Tags: errors, align

i'm having trouble with `align*` when i'm using any type of parenthesis.

Here is the code:

```
\begin{align*}  
V_o^\prime  &= A(V_2^+ -V_2^-) \\                       
&= A\left[0-\left(R_1\frac{V_o-V_o^'}{R_1+R_2}+V_o\right)\right] \\  !!!!!!!!!
V_o^\prime (R_1 +R_2)   &=  -AR_1V_o +AR_1V_o^\prime -AR_1V_o-AR_2V_o   \\  
        &= -2AR_1V_o +AR_1V_o^\prime -AR_2V_o               \\  
\end{align*}
```

The line with `!!!!` is the line that is troubling. I have already removed it from the code and the file compile perfectly

```
**Error message**

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.75 \end{align*}
```

Comment: Instead of `V_o^'` use `V_o'` or `V_o^\prime`.

Comment: I can´t believe it haha that was it, it is needed to write `V_o^\prime`. The problem was that I edited the equation in Mathematica so it will give me the code in LaTeX. 

Thanks a lot @GonzaloMedina

Comment: The "LaTeX" generated by such tools is awe-inspiringly awful, in my experience. Better go over what they generate, clean up and indent for readability. Yes, it hurts. But reading the code has been shown to cause eye cancer.

Comment: This looks 'too localized' to me, as it's a very specific issue. Perhaps you can edit the question to make it more general (Mathematica exporting `'` and messing up), or I think it's likely to get closed.